# Coldfusion onApplicationStart or?

Tags: coldfusion

I am running to an issue
I want to set some application variables after the onApplicationStart()
When I am trying it to call a cfm page at the end of the onApplicationStart() it give error like it is not finish to load
Is there a way to execute the script somewhere between onApplicationStart() and onRequesStart so these application variables would be loaded

Sorry I am newbie
I am running cf2021 Enterprise

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Calling a page in the onApplicationStart method seems odd.  What does the page do and what is the error that gets thrown?

Comment: Any code or errors?

Comment: I think we need some clarity as to why you have this requirement, before we can start to answer it. Firstly: it's pretty unorthodox to be wanting to manage app-scoped variables after onApplicationStart. By their very nature, they're supposed to exist for the lifetime of the app, so that's the place to be setting them. There will be exceptions to this, but I suspect you might have a design issue here which might warrant closer attn. Can you be more precise as to how you got into this perceived situation?

Comment: Many thanks Sir, by your comments I was able to rethink how to do it ) Thanks for your support

Comment: Mike it'd still be good to see what you were trying to do, and how you solved it. This site is about helping everyone (so future ppl landing here with similar questions) not just helping the OP.

Comment: Sure Adam, thanks
I am doing a advanced drone detection application
When the application Start need to fetch all the weather conditions to see if it is a go or no go situation to be able to fly
Now during the onApplicationStart() process it was like my code to fetch the drone info was too fast as the application start wasn't yet finished... it is the way I seen it. So as a kind gentlemen give me the idea of extend the component, if the application scope variables I was creating is not defined so then I run it before the session... Hard to explain in writing but I am happy it is working.

Comment: sorry by being new to coldfusion but I really like it... Thanks for your help again Adam

Comment: Based on what you are saying about the weather, either the `request` or `session` scopes seem more appropriate than does the `application` scope.

Comment: Thanks Dan Bracuk for your words 
I will try to study more about it and yes maybe you are right
At this point I don't know how the manage the request scope and what I can do with it. I have tried to learn about it but documentation is very little about it and what are the difference between these scopes. Thanks for your help and understanding

Comment: Here is some light reading for you  https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html

Answer (score 1):

The [onApplicationStart()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onapplicationstart.html) returns a boolean value only. If you want variables defined when the application starts, that's where you define them. You can include CFM files in there if you've got a ton for some reason, or you can create multiple `Application.cfc` files in subfolders that contain smaller "applications" tied to the main one.

```
/Applicatioon.cfc
/ApplicationProxy.cfc (extends Application.cfc)
/appA/Applicatioon.cfc (1)
/appB/Applicatioon.cfc (2)
/appC/Applicatioon.cfc (3)
```

1. Contains `application` variables for appA.
2. Contains `application` variables for appB.
3. Contains `application` variables for appC.

Each sub-folder's `Application.cfc` extends `../ApplicationProxy.cfc`. They also call `super.onApplicationStart()` at the top of their own `onApplicationStart()`. If someone enters the applications in the sub-folder, this forces the code to load the top-level `application` variables, then it loads that folder's variables.

You can also try using `onRequestStart()` and define them at the top, but you should check for a variable's existence before setting it so that you only define it once.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, you gave me hint so now I found the way about it, Many thanks for your help 
You are very kind. Mike